# MVCContrib Not Refresh JQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Hi I'm trying to refresh a mvccontrib grid, using ajax in MVC but it doesn't work. When I use "return PartialView("myview", mylist);" nothing happend. The response never came to the jquery code. I put the keyword debbuger to see if it works but never got there.

this is my JQuery Code to refresh the grid:

```
    function refreshTable() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false,
            cache: false
        });
        $.get('<%= Url.Action("RefreshGridData", "Countries") %>',
            function (response) {
                debugger;
                $(".table-list").replaceWith(response)
            });
    }
```

And this is my Action:

```
    public ActionResult RefreshGridData()
    {
        GetAllCountries();//this puts a list in the ViewData
        return PartialView("CountriesPage", (List<iCatalogData.Country>)ViewData["CountriesList"]);
    }
```

And this is my grid:

```
<div id="container">
    <% Html.Grid((List<iCatalogData.Country>)ViewData["CountriesList"])
           .Columns(column =>
           {
               column.For(co => Html.ActionLink(co.IdCountry.ToString(), "EditCountry", "Countries", new { id = co.IdCountry }, null)).Named("Id Country");
               column.For(co => co.CountryName);
               column.For(co => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCountry", "Countries", new { id = co.IdCountry }, null)).Named("Delete");
           }).Attributes(id => "example", @class => "table-list", style => "width: 100%;").Empty("No countries available").Render();

%>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Now the Request is okey but when the grid is rendered all the features of mvccontrib has gone, style, search, paging, etc. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: im not sure about this but instead of $('.table-list').replaceWith(...), you should try $('#container').replaceWith(...).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by changing the return type of the action to `PartialViewResult` instead of `ActionResult`. Could possibly be the same issue for you.

Comment: I actually solve the problem using PartialView but I have to put the grid in a PartialView too. And I have to use <% Html.RenderPartial("viewName", model); %>